# mkdir /path: read-only file system problems when running geth

Tags: python, docker, blockchain

I’m trying to reproduce the steps mentioned in this repo on github (https://github.com/koneksys/Blockchain4LinkedData) to execute the code but I’m having some problems with geth. Further more I’m using `Mac OS Catalina version 10.15 (19A583)`.

Steps to reproduce the error:

- clone the repo into a directory
- install go version 1.7, npm and node.js
- open terminal >> navigate to geth file and run make geth and after installing all the packages, run `geth --testnet --cache=512` console to see if geth is responding and showing transactions on the ledger.
- Navigate back to the Dapp file and run npm build, then  navigate back again to "Geth"
  And run the following command as mentioned in the repo

  `build/bin/geth --datadir  /path/to/Blockchain/Blockchain --mine --port 30301 --rpcport 8545 --networkid 1234 -- nodiscover --unlock 0 --password pas.txt --rpc --rpccorsdomain '*' -- rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,web3,miner"`

I get the following error :

```
Fatal: Failed to create the protocol stack: mkdir /path: read-only file system
```

After changing the directory name "/path/to/Blockchain/Blockchain" to my project working directoy I have managed to bypass the fatal error shown above. However when I navigate back to Dapp file to rund the command  `node server.js` to run the UI on localhost:3003 i get the following error:

```
rm@MacBook-Pro dapp % node server.js
/Users/rm/Desktop/block/Blockchain4LinkedData/Dapp/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:91
        throw errors.InvalidResponse(request.responseText);
        ^

Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: undefined
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/Users/rm/Desktop/block/Blockchain4LinkedData/Dapp/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:35:16)
    at HttpProvider.send (/Users/rm/Desktop/block/Blockchain4LinkedData/Dapp/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:91:22)
    at RequestManager.send (/Users/rm/Desktop/block/Blockchain4LinkedData/Dapp/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:58:32)
    at Eth.send [as getBlock] (/Users/rm/Desktop/block/Blockchain4LinkedData/Dapp/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:145:58)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/rm/Desktop/block/Blockchain4LinkedData/Dapp/app/routes.js:31:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
rm@MacBook-Pro dapp %
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: Thank you for providing a detailed explanation of your problem. Are you trying to write to a system or root folder? What happens if you change the `datadir` to a folder under you user directory `/Users/<your_usr_folder>/blockchain`

Comment: Did you really create a folder with the path "/path/to/Blockchain/Blockchain"?

Comment: @jwjhdev, i totally mist that one, the path name was referring to something that doesn’t exist, after redirecting it to the correct path name it suddenly started working

Comment: @MadJackal, no i didn't name it like  obliviously I but the developer of this code wrote it down to indicate that users should change the path and redirect it to the correct directory so i totally missed it :)

Comment: anyone have any idea how to solve the second error message?